# Guidance for the people who sit a lot

Tags: health

People I am working on internet and so i have to sit all day and night to do my Job. This has brought many disadvantages in me such as increase in thigh and belly weight, in activeness boredom and etc. But last but not the least i think i getting dull day by day.

PLEASE I need your help with your useful suggestions that how can i work and still work but remain as healthy and fresh as I was while starting my work!!

Comment: What are you asking? For excercises that will prvent "activeness boredom" at work? Lose the "belly weight"? Clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is the end result you are expecting? What do you have access to? What all can you do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don;t know much about you, so this may be inapropriate, but there are things called "treadmill desks" which allow you to work standing up and walking. Try Googling "treadmill desk" and you should get the idea.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=treadmill+desk&hl=en&btnG=Google+Search&sourceid=Mozilla-search&start=0

Comment: All I want is the exercises that will help me in
1- Loosing my belly and thigh fat
2- Stay active
3- Get rid of boredom and lazyness
4- Most importantly by sitting all day my senses have got dull so i would definitely like to know about the exercises that will help me to bring all these.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want is the exercises that will help me in 1- Loosing my belly
>   and thigh fat 2- Stay active 3- Get rid of boredom and lazyness 4-
>   Most importantly by sitting all day my senses have got dull so i would
>   definitely like to know about the exercises that will help me to bring
>   all these. – mirxasahib

`1- Loosing my belly and thigh fat`

- Highly unlikely you don't do any activity or with the activity level you are talking.
- Consider changing your food habit.

`2- Stay active`

- Do something activity. (How ironic)

`3- Get rid of boredom and lazyness`

- Read books.
- Get yourself interest in something and learn about it.
- For `Lazy-ness`, you have find inspiration. No hardcore external solution.

`4- Most importantly by sitting all day my senses have got dull so i would  definitely like to know about the exercises that will help me to bring all these.`

- There are exercises called [deskercise](http://greatist.com/fitness/deskercise-33-ways-exercise-work).

  1. The Twinkle Toe
  2. The Stair Master
  3. The Slog, Then Jog
  4. The Celebratory Split Squat Jumps
  5. The Cubicle Wanderer

> Most important of all make up your mind to be fit. No can make you fit. You have to become fit on your own. Without effort non of what you have asked can be achieved.